# Show that $L^{-1}\{(s^2+a^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\}=\frac{t}{a}J_1(ax)$

Tags: laplace-transform, bessel-functions

**Question:**

Assume that $J_\alpha(x)$ is defined as below:
$$J_\alpha(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!\, \Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+\alpha}.$$

> (a) Prove that  $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{-\alpha} J_\alpha(x))=-x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha+1}(x)$;
>
> (b) If $L\{J_0(ax)\}=\frac{1}{\sqrt {s^2+a^2}}$, show that
> $L^{-1}\{(s^2+a^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\}=\frac{x}{a}J_1(ax)$ .

I proved part (a). But about part (b), what I have is:

$$L^{-1}\{(s^2+a^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\}=L^{-1}\{({(s^2+a^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}})^{3}\}=J_0(x)*J_0(x)*J_0(x).$$

How should I reach $\frac{t}{a}J_1(ax)$ from $J_0(x)*J_0(x)*J_0(x)$  ?

Comment: You can use modifiers `\left` and `\right` to any braces to make them adjust their size to ther contents: `\left\{ ... \left( multi-level fraction \right)... \right\}`.

Comment: For part $(b)$, just compute the Laplace transform of $x\,J_1(ax)$ through the series definition and $\mathcal{L}(x^t)=\frac{t!}{s^{t+1}}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio As I did in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's write:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{x}{\text{a}}\cdot\mathscr{J}_\alpha\left(\text{b}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\mathscr{L}_x\left[x\cdot\mathscr{J}_\alpha\left(\text{b}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag1$$

Using the '[frequency-domain derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)' property of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform):

$$\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\mathscr{L}_x\left[x\cdot\mathscr{J}_\alpha\left(\text{b}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\mathscr{L}_x\left[\mathscr{J}_\alpha\left(\text{b}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\right\}\tag2$$

Using the '[time scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)' property of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)&=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\mathscr{L}_x\left[\mathscr{J}_\alpha\left(\text{b}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\right\}\\
\\
&=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\mathscr{L}_x\left[\mathscr{J}_\alpha\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)}\right\}\\
\\
&=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\mathscr{L}_x\left[\mathscr{J}_\alpha\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)}\right\}
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

Using the definition of the [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Definitions):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)&=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\mathscr{L}_x\left[\mathscr{J}_\alpha\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)}\right\}\\
\\
&=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\mathscr{L}_x\left[\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\alpha+2\text{n}}\right]_{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)}\right\}\\
\\
&=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\frac{1}{2^{\alpha+2\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+2\text{n}\right)}{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)^{1+\alpha+2\text{n}}}\right\}\\
\\
&=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{\alpha+2\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+2\text{n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left\{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)^{1+\alpha+2\text{n}}}\right\}\\
\\
&=-\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{\alpha+2\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+2\text{n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\left(-\frac{1+\alpha+2\text{n}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)^{1+\alpha+2\text{n}}}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{\alpha+2\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(2+\alpha+2\text{n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\alpha+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)^{1+\alpha+2\text{n}}}
\end{split}\tag4
\end{equation}

When $\Re\left(\alpha+2\text{n}\right)>-1\space\wedge\space\Re\left(\text{s}\right)>0$.

> Now, when $\alpha=1$:
>
> $$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{x}{\text{a}}\cdot\mathscr{J}_1\left(\text{b}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=$$
> $$\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{1+2\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(2+1+2\text{n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+1+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)^{1+1+2\text{n}}}=$$
> $$\frac{1}{\text{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{b}}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{1+2\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(3+2\text{n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{b}}\right)^{2+2\text{n}}}\tag5$$

Now, when $\text{a}=\text{b}$:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{x}{\text{a}}\cdot\mathscr{J}_1\left(\text{a}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\text{s}^3}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1+\left(\frac{\text{a}}{\text{s}}\right)^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\tag6$$

> Now, I let you prove:
>
> $$\frac{1}{\text{s}^3}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1+\left(\frac{\text{a}}{\text{s}}\right)^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{1}{\left(\text{s}^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\tag7$$

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort ... But I'm wondering if this question has a simpler solution...

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh First of all, you're welcome, I'm glad to help! Uhmm this is not a difficult solution.....!